# Pyautogui multithreading doesnt work?

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-3.x, kernel, pyautogui

This code works perfectly on the first run.

```
import time as t
import pyautogui as p
import threading

def skincare1():
    p.alert("skincare level 1",'skincare 1')
    t.sleep(0.3)
    p.alert("skincare level 2",'skincare 2')

print('start')

threadem=threading.Thread(target=skincare1)
threadem.start()

print('end')
```

But when I run it again, it prints out both 'start' and 'end', and after a couple of seconds:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

If I restart kernel it works fine for the first time again, but crashes on the second. 
Any idea why?

Edit:
If I take out the sleep part, it still runs good for the first time, but gives the same error on all further runs. But if I put in something really simple, like 'print ('middle part')' with sleep, it runs good always. So somehow this is caused by pyautogui.

```
import time as t
import pyautogui as p
import threading

def skincare1():
    p.alert("skincare level 1",'skincare 1')

print('start')

threadem=threading.Thread(target=skincare1)
threadem.start()

print('end')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the compiler itself decides which thread to run first and there may be a possibility that when you put your thread to sleep it doesnt get back alive due to which the start and end are displayed together and then when the compiler doesnt find and thread to issue it automatically sends an error.

Comment: @ Bhavishye Goswami 
unfortunately even without the 'sleep' it run good for the first time, but bad for the second